# Jpa Persist primary key restriction violation

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I'm having some problem on transitive persistence. Now I try to describe my problem in a more detailed way. I have two entities Row and Field.

```
    @Entity
public class Row implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name="ROW_IMPORT_ID_GENERATOR", sequenceName="SEQ_RIGA_IMPORT")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="ROW_IMPORT_ID_GENERATOR")
    private Long id;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to CampoImport
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="row", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Field> fields;

    //Getters and setters method

    public void addField(Field fieldToAdd){

        if(fields==null)
            fields = new ArrayList<Fields>();

        fields.add(campoToAdd);
        fieldToAdd.setRow(this);

    }
}


@Entity
public class Field implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name="FIELD_IMPORT_ID_GENERATOR", sequenceName="SEQ_CAMPO_IMPORT")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="FIELD_IMPORT_ID_GENERATOR")
    private Long id;

    private String description;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to RigaImport
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="ID_ROW")
    private Row row;

    //Getters and setters method
}
```

This is the sql statement to make the sequences:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE SEQ_RIGA_IMPORT INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1 MAXVALUE 999999999999999999 MINVALUE 1;

CREATE SEQUENCE SEQ_CAMPO_IMPORT INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1 MAXVALUE 999999999999999999 MINVALUE 1;
```

Now when i try to run the following snippet of code:

```
Row rowToSave = new Row(some parameters);
Field fieldToSave = new Field( some parameters);
rowToSave.addField(fieldToSave);
rowRepository.save(rowToSave);
```

I get this error:

```
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00001: violated    restriction of uniqueness (BILL.FIELD_PK)

Error Code: 1
Call: INSERT INTO FIELD (ID, DESCRIPTION, ID_ROW) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
bind => [3 parameters bound]
```

Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: Perhaps you have records that were created prior to using the sequence and already have the id of the sequence increment ?

Comment: Are you not persisting the field somewhere else again? The field will be persisted 'automactically' when you save the row, so if you persist it in another place you will have double insert (as the id wiil be already set during your first save).

Comment: Try setting logging to log the parameters being used: https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Logging but I suspect your sequence starting at 1 and incrementing by 1 is the cause of the problem.  JPA defaults to incrementing by 50, and so is likely trying to use values -49 to 1.  Set the sequence allocationSize to match your database sequence object

Comment: @Chris What do you intend when you said *JPA defaults to incrementing by 50, and so is likely trying to use values -49 to 1*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your database sequence object has an allocation size of 1, while JPA defaults to 50 which will cause this issue.  Set your allocation size to match.  see https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Entities/Ids/SequenceGenerator